# ABCpdf 11.3 - Unable to load the html

Tags: abcpdf

We are using ABCPdf 11.3 for one of our clients. We create HTML dynamically and then store it somewhere on the server.

We call the AddImageUrl(filePath, False, 300, False) and it takes more than 2 minutes even for a single page. (filePath is something like 'file://E:/pankaj/{generatedpdf}.html"

I need to improve application performance. Since it's a single page, it shouldn't take more than 10 seconds. Even if I pass [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as the parameter, it converts the google home to PDF in 10 seconds.

Appreciate your help friends.

Comment: ABCpdf version 11 uses the Chrome engine by default which can be very fussy about local file paths. You could try one of the other HTML rendering engines. If you have a valid license ABCpdf support will be able to help you for free.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved.

I could see there were a lot of external links and some javascript code on the page which was passed to ABCpdf to convert entirely.

I removed the scripts and the external CSS/js libraries and all other external links and it worked. Now the page is rendered within 2 seconds.

Thank you!